# NPM is not giving any output

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I am a Windows User having issues setting up my node environment. I downloaded the Node installer, and installed it. In powershell, I can use node as intended, and it works fine. However, entering either npm or npx commands do not give any output. No error message, nothing.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\XXX> npm -v
(base) PS C:\Users\XXX>
```

Approaches I tried so far:

- I made sure, that in the systems path is only the path to the Node folder, no other npm path.
- Deinstalled chocholatey
- Reinstalling the Node installer
- Running the npm.bat from powershell -> no output.

Interestingly, when I do the same in cygwin, npm is working fine.
Anyone had the same experience?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. After testing every setting, I was sure, that the problem was not due to node itself or the paths.

Since npm is started via a cmd script, I try to run it in the command prompt (not in powershell). However, opening the command promt led to it immediatly closing. I could fix this issue by removing the Autorun scripts (see [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/571715/windows-command-line-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operab/571717#571717)). Now it works like a charm.